# How to find in a parent string list, the indexes corresponding to a child string list

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, indexing

I am writing a code which reads data from a text file. I load the data using numpy [loadtxt](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.loadtxt.html&ei=1RU5VdHQAYuO7AbjuIH4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHn0nfFa-hFfHa_82Fnz4PssUIVlw&sig2=ED4HgmHzzF1PcmdwiCtmqg&bvm=bv.91427555,d.ZWU) and it could look like something like this:

```
import numpy as np

Shop_Products  = np.array(['Tomatos', 'Bread' , 'Tuna', 'Milk', 'Cheese'])
Shop_Inventory = np.array([12, 6, 10, 7, 8])
```

I want to check some of the products I have:

```
Shop_Query     = np.array(['Cheese', 'Bread']
```

Now I would like to find these "items" indeces in the Shop_Products array without doing a for loop and if checks.

I wondered if it could be done with any of the numpy methods: I thought of using  a [intercept1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to find the common items and then use [searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). However, I cannot sort my "Products" list since I do not want to loose the original sorting (for example I would use the indexes to directly look for the inventory of each product).

Any advice on the "pythonish" solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) can take a sorting permutation as an optional argument:

```
>>> sorter = np.argsort(Shop_Products)
>>> sorter[np.searchsorted(Shop_Products, Shop_Query, sorter=sorter)]
array([4, 1])
>>> Shop_Inventory[sorter[np.searchsorted(Shop_Products, Shop_Query, sorter=sorter)]]
array([8, 6])
```

This is probably faster than `np.in1d`, which also needs to sort the array. It also returns values in the same order as they come up in `Shop_Query`, while `np.1d` will return the values in the order they come up in `Shop_Products`, regardless of the ordering in the query:

```
>>> np.in1d(Shop_Products, ['Cheese', 'Bread']).nonzero()
(array([1, 4]),)
>>> np.in1d(Shop_Products, ['Bread', 'Cheese']).nonzero()
(array([1, 4]),)
```

Comment: I like this solution better than my `in1d` one - the ability to return the indices according to the order the query seems particularly useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `in1d()` and `nonzero()` to find the indices of the items in `Shop_Products`:

```
>>> np.in1d(Shop_Products, Shop_Query).nonzero()
(array([1, 4]),)
```

(`in1d` returns a boolean array indicating whether an item is in the second list, `nonzero` returns the indices of the `True` values.)

To look up the corresponding values in `Shop_Inventory`, use this result to index the array:

```
>>> i = np.in1d(Shop_Products, Shop_Query).nonzero()
>>> Shop_Inventory[i]
array([6, 8])
```