# Getting the indices of several elements in a NumPy array at once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any way to get the indices of several elements in a NumPy array at once?

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 10, 4])
```

I would like to find the index of each element of `a` in `b`, namely: `[0,1,4]`.

I find the solution I am using a bit verbose:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 10, 4])

c = np.zeros_like(a)
for i, aa in np.ndenumerate(a):
    c[i] = np.where(b == aa)[0]
    
print('c: {0}'.format(c))
```

Output:

```
c: [0 1 4]
```

Comment: np.where(np.in1d(b,a)) returns  (array([0, 1, 4], dtype=int64),). Based on last example at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could use [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) (or `where` for that matter):

```
>>> np.in1d(b, a).nonzero()[0]
array([0, 1, 4])
```

This works fine for your example arrays, but in general the array of returned indices does not honour the order of the values in `a`. This may be a problem depending on what you want to do next.

In that case, a much better answer is the one @Jaime gives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829495/3923281), using `searchsorted`:

```
>>> sorter = np.argsort(b)
>>> sorter[np.searchsorted(b, a, sorter=sorter)]
array([0, 1, 4])
```

This returns the indices for values as they appear in `a`. For instance:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([4, 2, 3, 1])

>>> sorter = np.argsort(b)
>>> sorter[np.searchsorted(b, a, sorter=sorter)]
array([3, 1, 0]) # the other method would return [0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: The documentation now recommends using [`isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) instead of `in1d`.

Comment: Thanks for the ordered version! @ArcturusB: where do you find this information about the recommendation of using isin instead of in1d?

Comment: @Elendil: in the [documentation of `in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) : “We recommend using isin instead of in1d for new code.”

Comment: @ArcturusB: Oh didn't see it. I'm stucked to old version ([1.11.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L385) and this was not yet the case). It seems to appear in the [1.13.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L385) release. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

This is a simple one-liner using the [numpy-indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = npi.indices(b, a)
```

The implementation is fully vectorized, and it gives you control over the handling of missing values. Moreover, it works for nd-arrays as well (for instance, finding the indices of rows of a in b).

Comment: This works great. Even for strings, which is what I was looking for

Comment: does not seem to work with nd arrays...

Answer (score 5):

For an order-agnostic solution, you can use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) (v 1.13+).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 10, 4])

res = np.flatnonzero(np.isin(a, b))  # NumPy v1.13+
res = np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(a, b))  # earlier versions

# array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This works beautifully for what I needed.

Comment: What a nice solution! However, for anyone who tumbles into this solution, please switch the position of the two arrays to get the expected result: ```np.flatnonzero(a=np.isin(element=b, test_elements=a)```.

Answer (score 3):

All of the solutions here recommend using a linear search. You can use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to speed things up dramatically for large arrays:

```
sorter = b.argsort()
i = sorter[np.searchsorted(b, a, sorter=sorter)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of approaches for getting the index of multiple items at once mentioned in passing in answers to this related question: [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array). The wide variety and creativity of the answers suggests there is no single best practice, so if your code above works and is easy to understand, I'd say keep it.

I personally found this approach to be both performant and easy to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994923/3823857

Adapting it for your example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b_list = [1, 2, 3, 10, 4]
b_array = np.array(b_list)

indices = [b_list.index(x) for x in a]
vals_at_indices = b_array[indices]
```

I personally like adding a little bit of error handling in case a value in `a` does not exist in `b`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b_list = [1, 2, 3, 10, 4]
b_array = np.array(b_list)
b_set = set(b_list)

indices = [b_list.index(x) if x in b_set else np.nan for x in a]
vals_at_indices = b_array[indices]
```

For my use case, it's pretty fast, since it relies on parts of Python that are fast (list comprehensions, .index(), sets, numpy indexing). Would still love to see something that's a NumPy equivalent to VLOOKUP, or even a Pandas merge. But this seems to work for now.

Comment: i wouldnt recommend using loops for something that has a vectorized solution