# Polygon as a numpy matrix mask

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have `x` and `y` numpy matrixes of coordinates. `.shape` of each is (1000,1200). `x` and `y` have been created in fact with `np.meshgrid()`. I also created `z`, a numpy matrix of zeros same size as the fore-mentioned `x`,`y`. I have a polygon defined by its vertices. 
What's the fastest way to substitute in `z` the zeros inside that polygon to ones values?

I tried `matplotlib.path` and `Shapely` functions, but all solutions seem to take too long. Can you provide me with a quick implementation that can easily handle [1000x1200] matrixes?

Comment: You could try the [ray casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm from [Rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm#Python).

Comment: You could use this [`post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array) to get the row indices whose `z's` are to be updated.

Comment: hi what should I do if my points in polygons are of float type

Comment: @MeghaRawat Can't remember exactly this, but points in polygons should be of float type as well. In that case you would substitute `0.` to the to-be-masked points, if that it is still your goal... Or are you referring to a specific algorithm in particular?

Comment: my scenario is
I have used labelme annotation tool to annotate my images and those annotations are ploygons which are in float type and I have use polygon_to_mask() function from here (https://pypkg.com/pypi/labelme/f/labelme/utils.py) to convert my annotations to nparray but it is returning me (0.) in whole array.

Comment: I think you can convert it to mask or logical zeroes, as in the `def polygons_to_mask` of the `utils.py` function you refer to. If that is not enough, then I would suggest to public a new question out of your post, perhaps with more context, code snippet and, above all, YOUR GOAL. Good luck

Comment: @giosans https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/111 any suggestions? 
thank you