# Find 1D array from 2D NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Suppose I have

```
[[array([x1, y1]), z1]
 [array([x2, y1]), z2]
 ......
 [array([xn, yn]), zn]
]
```

And I want to find the index of `array([x5, y5])`. How can find effieciently using NumPy?

Comment: Why do you have a python list of 1D numpy arrays instead of just a 2D numpy array?

Comment: I was making Tic Tac Toe using reinforment learning so every row contains the board configuration (every board can be distinguished by 2 attributes) and the V(s) score

Comment: I don;t know if any numpy functions will save you since you have everything in an awkward mix of python lists and numpy arrays. Why not just standard python `.index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, owing to the mixed data format, I don't think you can extract the arrays in a vectorized manner. Thus, you can use `loop comprehension` to extract the first element corresponding to the arrays from each list element as a `2D` array. So, let's say `A` is the input list, we would have -

```
arr = np.vstack([a[0] for a in A])
```

Then, simply do the comparison in a vectorized fashion using [`NumPy's broadcasting feature`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), as it will broadcast that comparison along all the rows and look all matching rows with `np.all(axis=1)`. Finally, use `np.flatnonzero` to get the final indices. Thus, the final peace of the puzzle would be -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero((arr == search1D).all(1))
```

You can read up on the answers to [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array) to see other alternatives to get indices in such a `1D` array searching in `2D` array problem.

Sample run -

```
In [140]: A
Out[140]: 
[[array([3, 4]), 11],
 [array([2, 1]), 12],
 [array([4, 2]), 16],
 [array([2, 1]), 21]]

In [141]: search1D = [2,1]

In [142]: arr = np.vstack([a[0] for a in A]) # Extract 2D array

In [143]: arr
Out[143]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [2, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [2, 1]])

In [144]: np.flatnonzero((arr == search1D).all(1)) # Finally get indices
Out[144]: array([1, 3])
```