# Using searchsorted for 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to have the index like function :`np.searchsorted([1,2,3,4,5], 3)` returns 2 but in case 2-D dimension: `np.searchsorted([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], [5,6])` should return 2. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you really doing `search` for `sorted` location?  Or is this some sort of `find`?  Are you searching for items that are in the array; or place to put new ones?

Comment: Just do `searchsorted` on the 1st column. If you are worried about ties, calculate some function of the columns that resolves the issue. `searchsorted` only makes sense if sorting of the array is well defined.  It isn't a substitute for list index or find.

Comment: For multiple values, you could take a look here : [`Find the row indexes of several values in a numpy array`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array).

Comment: Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([5,6])
np.where(np.all(a==b,axis=1))
```

Comment: Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) indicates that it only works on 1-D arrays.

You can find the index location in a list using built-in methds:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> a.index([5,6])
2

>>> a = [[1,2],[5,6],[3,4]]
>>> print(a.index([5,6]))
>>> a.sort()
>>> print(a.index([5,6]))
1
2
```

Comment: Thank for your help!