# Replacing pixel np.array values in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have an image as a np.array which has shape (320, 240, 4). I want to replace all the individual pixels that have array value (1, 0, 0, 1) which is red to green which has array value (0, 1, 0, 1). I've tried using `np.all()` but it's not working though I don't get any errors. Below is my code:

```
mario = mpimg.imread("mario_big.png")
print(mario.shape) # (320, 240, 4)

mario[np.all(mario == (1, 0, 0, 1), axis=-1)] = (0, 1, 0, 1)
luigi = mario

plt.imshow(luigi)
plt.show()
```

mario looks like this:

```
[[[0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  ...
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]]

 [[0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  ...
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]]

 [[0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  ...
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]
  [0.        0.        0.        0.       ]]

 ...
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please share your input image.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68381142/6331369)):

```
>>> mario = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3, 2, 4))
array([[[1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1]], ## <-

       [[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1]]])

>>> mario[np.all(mario == (1, 0, 0, 1), axis=-1)] =  (0, 1, 0, 1)

>>> mario
array([[[1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1]], ## <-

       [[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1]]])
```

Comment: Hmm but my colors are not changing from red to green.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to convert from array to image?

Comment: Oh I just did `plt.imshow()`. I added code in question.

Comment: I would assume your image is encoded in `[0, 255]`, if that's the case then you should do something like `mario[np.all(mario == (255, 0, 0, 255), axis=-1)] =  (0, 255, 0, 255)` instead.

Comment: I don't think so. The given image is an RGBA np array with all pixel values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Please make sure that's the case by looking at `mario.min()` and `mario.max()`. The `matplotlib.pyplot.imread` function should return a `[0, 255]`-range array, I just checked.

Comment: Checked using mario.min() and mario.max() which returns 0 and 1. Could I use np.isclose() here somehow maybe some pixels have extremely small difference?

Comment: Could you share the image?