# Numpy Array Set Difference

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that have overlapping rows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2], [1,5], [3,4], [3,5], [4,1], [4,6]])
b = np.array([[1,5], [3,4], [4,6]])
```

You can assume that:

1. the rows are sorted
2. the rows within each array is unique
3. array `b` is always subset of array `a`

I would like to get an array that contains all rows of `a` that are not in `b`.

i.e.,:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 5]
 [4 1]]
```

Considering that `a` and `b` can be very, very large, what is the most efficient method for solving this problem?

Comment: You mention the rows are sorted. Is the full array also sorted column-wise?

Comment: Other recent row set questions: (intersection) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218768/find-numpy-vectors-in-a-set-quickly/39220519#39220519, (union) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083549/python-2-d-array-get-the-function-as-np-unique-or-union1d

Comment: Padraic - I think there are better duplicates than that. It dates from 2012, and there have been many questions about row sets or unique rows since then.

Comment: @hpaulj, feel from to reopen and re-dupe but if you look at the answer below it seems to be almost  a literal copy of  this highest rated  answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903368/2141635 from the dupe.

Comment: How many columns?  Always 2?

Comment: Yes, always two columns

Answer (score 7):

Here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 6]])
b = np.array([[3, 4], [4, 6]])

a1_rows = a.view([('', a.dtype)] * a.shape[1])
a2_rows = b.view([('', b.dtype)] * b.shape[1])
c = np.setdiff1d(a1_rows, a2_rows).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
print c
```

I think using [numpy.setdiff1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) is the right choice here

Comment: Use the `assume_unique=True` parameter if applicable.  Also look at the code for this function and `np.in1d`.  It might give ideas on how do things faster.  Other `row set` questions have proposed other ways of converting `a` and `b` to 1d for use in these functions.