# Check if numpy array rows are in another 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I find those row indices of numpy array `a` that are not already in `ref`?

For instance for this example:

```
ref = np.asarray([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4, 5, 6]])
a = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4, 5, 5]])
```

A result of `[0, 2]` would be correct, because these rows in `a` are not in `ref`. A possible solution would be to iterate over each row in `a` and check if it's in `ref`, but I was hoping there's a more efficient and elegant (1-liner?) way.

Note: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055835/removing-elements-from-an-array-that-are-in-another-array) doesn't work because it is assuming integer elements of the array (in my case I use floating point numbers).

Comment: There's an efficient 2-liner in the above link.

Comment: Ok, slight alteration to my initial question: I actually use floating point values in which case your suggestion doesn't work (will update my example).

Comment: Actually, there's a range of options suggested at your link. One seems to be working fine. I guess this can be deleted as suggested.