# Get rows of a first array matching rows of a second one

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have an array `A` of shape `(M, K)` and another `B` of shape `(N, K)`.

The rows of `B` are all the possible patterns that can be encountered (each pattern is thus a 1D array of size `K`).

I thus would like to get an array `C` of shape `(M,)` where `C[i]` is the indice of the pattern (in `B`) of row `i` in `A`.

I am currently doing this in a loop (i.e. looping over all the possible patterns) but I would end up using vectorization.

Here is an example:

```
A = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
B = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
```

I am expecting:

```
C = np.array([1, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/3293881), here's a vectorized solution using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
dims = B.max(0)+1
A1D = np.ravel_multi_index(A.T,dims)
B1D = np.ravel_multi_index(B.T,dims)
sidx = B1D.argsort()
out = sidx[np.searchsorted(B1D,A1D,sorter=sidx)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: A
Out[43]: 
array([[72, 89, 75],
       [72, 89, 75],
       [93, 38, 61],
       [47, 67, 50],
       [47, 67, 50],
       [93, 38, 61],
       [72, 89, 75]])

In [44]: B
Out[44]: 
array([[47, 67, 50],
       [93, 38, 61],
       [41, 55, 27],
       [72, 89, 75]])

In [45]: out
Out[45]: array([3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3])
```