# Numpy, new array based on an array within an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looping over an array to extract data but it's too slow. Is there a function in numpy that will do this faster? I have to create a new array based on values from an array within an array.

For example, create an array with cars made in USA.

```
    input: array = [['ford', 'USA'], ['volkswagen', 'Germany'], ['jeep', 'USA']]

    output: new_array = [['ford', 'USA'], ['jeep', 'USA']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an array of string dtype, you can slice out the second column and compare against the string `'USA'` to get a boolean array. This boolean array could then be used for indexing into the array using [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to select valid rows and give us the desired output.

Thus, the implementation would be simply -

```
array[array[:,1] == 'USA']
```

Comment: Thank you! @Divakar

Comment: How would I write it if I want a result based on two values? For exampel 'jeep' and 'USA'

Comment: @elfving Use `np.in1d`.

Comment: @elfving Also have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array) to get those indices and then simply index  into the list with those indices.