# Find n-dimensional point in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am investigating whether storing points in a numpy array helps me search for points, and I have several questions about it.

I have a Point class that represents a 3-dimensional point.

```
class Point( object ):
  def __init__( self, x, y, z ):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def __repr__( self ):
    return "<Point (%r, %r, %r)>" % ( self.x, self.y, self.z )
```

I build a list of Point objects.  Notice that the coordinates `(1, 2, 3)` deliberately occurs twice;  that is what I am going to search for.

```
>>> points = [Point(1, 2, 3), Point(4, 5, 6), Point(1, 2, 3), Point(7, 8, 9)]
```

I store the Point objects in a numpy array.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> npoints = numpy.array( points )
>>> npoints
array([<Point (1, 2, 3)>, <Point (4, 5, 6)>, <Point (1, 2, 3)>,
   <Point (7, 8, 9)>], dtype=object)
```

I search for all points with coordinates `(1, 2, 3)` in the following manner.

```
>>> numpy.where( npoints == Point(1, 2, 3) )
>>> (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

But, the result is not useful.  So, that does not seem to be the correct way to do it.  Is `numpy.where` the thing to use?  Is there another way to express the condition for `numpy.where` that would be successful?

The next thing I try is to store just the coordinates of the points in a numpy array.

```
>>> npoints = numpy.array( [(p.x, p.y, p.z) for p in points ])
>>> npoints
array([[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2, 3],
      [7, 8, 9]])
```

I search for all points with coordinates `(1,2,3)` in the following manner.

```
>>> numpy.where( npoints == [1,2,3] )
(array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

The result is, at least, something I can deal with.  The array of row indexes in the first return value, `array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2])`, does indeed tell me that the coordinates I am searching for are in rows 0 and 2 of `npoints`.  I could get away with doing something like the following.

```
>>> rows, cols = numpy.where( npoints == [1,2,3] )
>>> rows
array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2])
>>> cols
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> foundRows = set( rows )
>>> foundRows
set([0, 2])
>>> for r in foundRows:
...   # Do something with npoints[r]
```

However, I feel that I am not really using `numpy.where` appropriately, and that I am just getting lucky in this particular situation.

What is the appropriate way to find all occurrences of a n-dimensional point (i.e., a row with particular values) in a numpy array?

Preserving the order of the array is essential.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/) helps.

Comment: Don't use `numpy` arrays of custom objects. The problem is that `==` is implemented by *identity* for custom objects by default. Regardless, the biggest issue is that you are essentially creating an inefficient Python `list` when you make a `dtype=object` array.

Comment: Also consider the `Point` class from [`shapely`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).

Comment: In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array) suggested by @Divakar, approach #1 works.  I do not grok the syntax enough to know **why** it works yet.  That will keep me busy for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a “rich comparison” method `object.__eq__(self, other)` inside your `Point` class to be able to use `==` among `Point` objects:

```
class Point( object ):
  def __init__( self, x, y, z ):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def __repr__( self ):
    return "<Point (%r, %r, %r)>" % ( self.x, self.y, self.z )
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y and self.z == other.z

import numpy
points = [Point(1, 2, 3), Point(4, 5, 6), Point(1, 2, 3), Point(7, 8, 9)]
npoints = numpy.array( points )
found = numpy.where(npoints == Point(1, 2, 3))
print(found) # => (array([0, 2]),)
```

Comment: Adding a equality rich comparison method to the Point class is a good idea.  That worked.

Comment: I should type faster!   :)   Adding a equality rich comparison method to the Point class works, and is a good example in general.  However, in my situation, the Point class I am actually using is in a third party module which I am not able to modify.  Also, as @juanpa.arrivillaga brings up, letting the item data type of a numpy array be an object defeats the efficiency of using a numpy array.  I suspected that.  But, I might continue with this arrangement anyway.  Speed is not my primary concern, and it could be more convenient that using the list `index` method.