# What is an intuitive explanation of np.unravel_index?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I have read the documentation for [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) and played around with the function, but I can't figure out what it is doing.

Comment: Converts the linear indices to indexes along each of the axes given the shape of the nd-grid that forms those axes. [`Here's some explanation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/) going the other way for `np.ravel_multi_index`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Computer memory is addressed linearly. Each memory cell corresponds to a number. A block of memory can be addressed in terms of a base, which is the memory address of its first element, and the item index. For example, assuming the base address is 10,000:

```
item index      0       1       2       3
memory address  10,000  10,001  10,002  10,003
```

To store multi-dimensional blocks, their geometry must somehow be made to fit into linear memory. In `C` and `NumPy`, this is done row-by-row. A 2D example would be:

```
  | 0      1      2      3
--+------------------------
0 | 0      1      2      3
1 | 4      5      6      7
2 | 8      9     10     11
```

So, for example, in this 3-by-4 block the 2D index `(1, 2)` would correspond to the linear index `6` which is `1 x 4 + 2`.

`unravel_index` does the inverse. Given a linear index, it computes the corresponding `ND` index. Since this depends on the block dimensions, these also have to be passed. So, in our example, we can get the original 2D index `(1, 2)` back from the linear index `6`:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(6, (3, 4))
(1, 2)
```

Note: The above glosses over a few details. 1) Translating the item index to memory address also has to account for item size. For example, an integer typically has 4 or 8 bytes. So, in the latter case, the memory address for item `i` would be `base + 8 x i`. 2). NumPy is a bit more flexible than suggested. It can organize `ND` data column-by-column if desired. It can even handle data that are not contiguous in memory but for example leave gaps, etc.

---

Bonus reading: [internal memory layout of an ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray)

Comment: I'm just curious to understand this a bit more. Where can I find more information regarding this? Any suggestions please?

Comment: @kmario23 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Comment: @kmario23, you may access it here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html. This is from the official documentation

Comment: For a square matrix, the indices can be calculated: ```np.unravel_index(i, (n, n)) == (i//n, i%n)```

Answer (score 85):

We will start with an example in the documentation.

```
>>> np.unravel_index([22, 41, 37], (7,6))
(array([3, 6, 6]), array([4, 5, 1]))
```

First, `(7,6)` specifies the dimension of target array that we want to turn the indices back into. Second, `[22, 41, 37]` are some indices on this array **if the array is flattened.** If a 7 by 6 array is flattened, its indices will look like

```
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, *22*, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
   34, 35, 36, *37*, 38, 39, 40, *41*]
```

If we unflatten these indices back to their original positions in a dim `(7, 6)` array, it would be

```
      [[ 0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
       [ 6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11],
       [12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17],
       [18,  19,  20,  21, *22*, 23],  <- (3, 4)
       [24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
       [30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35],
       [36, *37*, 38,  39,  40, *41*]]
           (6, 1)               (6,5)
```

The return values of the `unravel_index` function tell you **what should have been the indices of [22, 41, 37]** if the array is not flattened. These indices should have been `[(3, 4), (6, 5), (6,1)]` if the array is not flattened. In other words, the function transfers the indices in a flatten array back to its unflatten version.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html

Comment: Frankly I think the output should have been [(3, 4), (6, 5), (6,1)] in your example instead of its transpose in the documentation, in order to consistent with the output of np.unravel_index(1621, (6,7,8,9)) being (3, 1, 4, 1)

Comment: this is much more intuitive than the first post

Answer (score 53):

This isn't different in content than the other two answers, but it might be more intuitive. If you have a 2-D matrix, or array, you can reference it in different ways. You could type the (row, col), to get the value at (row, col), or you can give each cell a single-number index. unravel_index just translates between these two ways of referencing values in a matrix.

[image]

This is extendable to dimensions larger than 2. You should also be aware of np.ravel_multi_index(), which performs the reverse transformation. Note that it requires the (row, col) and the shape of the array.

I also see I have two 10s in the index matrix--whoops.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for as far as intuition goes, thank you. May I ask, is the motivation for doing this simply because it makes calculations less computationally complex/easier to store in memory?

Comment: I would imagine there are many reasons/applications. One way I've used it significantly is this: I have a skeleton of single-width pixels that I need to walk along and return coordinates of where I've walked. It's much simpler for me to work in the "index" space rather than the "row, col" space because it cuts the number of operations in half. For example, if you want to see if you've already walked to (2,1), you'd have to check for 2, then check for 1. With indexing, I just check for "7". Basic example, but it really simplifies things. And to reiterate, there are many other applications :)

Answer (score 4):

I can explain it with very simple example. This is for **np.ravel_multi_index** as well as **np.unravel_index**

```
>>> X = np.array([[4,  2],
                  [9,  3],
                  [8,  5],
                  [3,  3],
                  [5,  6]])
>>> X.shape
(5, 2)
```

Find where all the **value 3** presents in X:

```
>>> idx = np.where(X==3)
>>> idx
(array([1, 3, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

i.e. `x = [1,3,3]` , `y = [1,0,1]`
It returns the x, y of indices (because X is 2-dimensional).

---

If you apply **ravel_multi_index** for `idx` obtained:

```
>>> idx_flat = np.ravel_multi_index(idx, X.shape)
>>> idx_flat
array([3, 6, 7], dtype=int64)
```

`idx_flat` is a linear index of X where value 3 presents.

From the above example, we can understand:

- ravel_multi_index converts multi-dimensional indices (nd array) into single-dimensional indices (linear array)
- It works only on indices i.e. both input and output are indices

The result indices will be direct indices of `X.ravel()`. You can verify in the below `x_linear`:

```
>>> x_linear = X.ravel()
>>> x_linear
array([4, 2, 9, 3, 8, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6])
```

---

Whereas, **unravel_index** is very simple, just reverse of above (np.ravel_multi_index)

```
>>> idx = np.unravel_index(idx_flat , X.shape)
>>> idx
(array([1, 3, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Which is same as `idx = np.where(X==3)`

- unravel_index converts single-dimensional indices (linear array) into multi-dimensional indices (nd array)
- It works only on indices i.e. both input and output are indices

Answer (score 0):

Given a `raveled_index` into a [`.ravel()`ed](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) array, [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) figures out the equivalent unraveled index into the base array:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.random.random((100, 42))
raveled_array = my_array.ravel()

raveled_index = 1337
unraveled_index = np.unravel_index(raveled_index, my_array.shape)

assert raveled_array[raveled_index] == my_array[unraveled_index]
```

---

Two nice to knows:

1. A `raveled_array` is also called a `flat_array`; hence a `raveled_index` or `flat_index` is nothing but an index into the "flattened" array. Further, since the flat array has "lost" its original shape information you need to add this when calling `np.unravel_index`.
2. The `unraveled_index` is typically called a `multi_index`. This is because you need multiple values (an N-tuple) to index an element in any array with `my_array.dim == N`. The inverse of `np.unravel_index` is thus called [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html).

Answer (score -1):

This is only applicable for the 2D case, but the two coordinates np.unravel_index functions returns in this case are equivalent to doing floor division and applying the modulo function respectively.

```
for j in range(1,1000):
    for i in range(j):
        assert(np.unravel_index(i,(987654321,j))==(i//j,i%j))
```

The first element of the shape array (ie 987654321) is meaningless except to put an upper bound on how large an unraveled linear index can be passed through the function.