How to get the index of an ordinal value from a numpy 3d array?
I have a 3d array of shape: (2, 3, 3) from which I would like to get the index of the 10th value. I have built a program through the conventional method of using loops.
Below is my solution:
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(1, 19).reshape(2, 3, 3)
el = 10
count = 0
loc = ()
for each_arr in np.arange(arr.shape[0]):
    for row in np.arange(arr.shape[1]):
        for col in np.arange(arr.shape[2]):
            count = col + arr.shape[2] * row + each_arr * arr.shape[1] * arr.shape[2]
            # print(count, end=" ")
            print(arr[each_arr, row, col], end=" ")
            if (count + 1) == el:
                loc = (each_arr, row, col)
                # print(f"{arr[each_arr, row, col]} at {(each_arr, row, col)}")
        print()
    print()

print(f"{el} element at {loc}")

I'd like to ask that, Is there a numpy way to accomplish this(Any kinds of comments are welcome)?

10th value in the ravelled array? np.unravel_index` https://stackoverflow.com/q/48135736/901925

Actually yes. It's returning (1, 0, 1) for  "index = np.unravel_index(10, arr.shape)". I just need to decrement the last index of the result with 1 to make it (1, 0, 0).
But just being curious, Why only the final item of the result needs to be decremented where all the others items of the tuple seem to be valid?
Thanks for your time and effort though.

The tenth element would have the index 9. Python uses 0-based indexing.
