# What is the fastest way to map group names of numpy array to indices?

Tags: python, numpy, hash, grouping, lidar

I'm working with 3D pointcloud of Lidar. The points are given by numpy array that looks like this:

```
points = np.array([[61651921, 416326074, 39805], [61605255, 416360555, 41124], [61664810, 416313743, 39900], [61664837, 416313749, 39910], [61674456, 416316663, 39503], [61651933, 416326074, 39802], [61679969, 416318049, 39500], [61674494, 416316677, 39508], [61651908, 416326079, 39800], [61651908, 416326087, 39802], [61664845, 416313738, 39913], [61674480, 416316668, 39503], [61679996, 416318047, 39510], [61605290, 416360572, 41118], [61605270, 416360565, 41122], [61683939, 416313004, 41052], [61683936, 416313033, 41060], [61679976, 416318044, 39509], [61605279, 416360555, 41109], [61664837, 416313739, 39915], [61674487, 416316666, 39505], [61679961, 416318035, 39503], [61683943, 416313004, 41054], [61683930, 416313042, 41059]])
```

**I'd like to keep my data grouped into cubes of size `50*50*50` so that every cube preserves some hashable index and numpy indices of my `points` it contains**. In order to get splitting, I assign `cubes = points \\ 50` which outputs to:

```
cubes = np.array([[1233038, 8326521, 796], [1232105, 8327211, 822], [1233296, 8326274, 798], [1233296, 8326274, 798], [1233489, 8326333, 790], [1233038, 8326521, 796], [1233599, 8326360, 790], [1233489, 8326333, 790], [1233038, 8326521, 796], [1233038, 8326521, 796], [1233296, 8326274, 798], [1233489, 8326333, 790], [1233599, 8326360, 790], [1232105, 8327211, 822], [1232105, 8327211, 822], [1233678, 8326260, 821], [1233678, 8326260, 821], [1233599, 8326360, 790], [1232105, 8327211, 822], [1233296, 8326274, 798], [1233489, 8326333, 790], [1233599, 8326360, 790], [1233678, 8326260, 821], [1233678, 8326260, 821]])
```

#### My desired output looks like this:

```
{(1232105, 8327211, 822): [1, 13, 14, 18]), 
(1233038, 8326521, 796): [0, 5, 8, 9], 
(1233296, 8326274, 798): [2, 3, 10, 19], 
(1233489, 8326333, 790): [4, 7, 11, 20], 
(1233599, 8326360, 790): [6, 12, 17, 21], 
(1233678, 8326260, 821): [15, 16, 22, 23]}
```

My real pointcloud contains up to few hundreds of millions of 3D points. What is the fastest way to do this kind of grouping?

I've tried a majority of various solutions. Here is comparison of time compsumption assuming size of points is arround 20 millions and size of distinct cubes is arround 1 million:

#### Pandas [tuple(elem) -> np.array(dtype=int64)]

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame(cubes).groupby([0,1,2]).indices)
#takes 9sec
```

#### Defauldict [elem.tobytes() or tuple -> list]

```
#thanks @abc:
result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, elem in enumerate(cubes):
    result[elem.tobytes()].append(idx) # takes 20.5sec
    # result[elem[0], elem[1], elem[2]].append(idx) #takes 27sec
    # result[tuple(elem)].append(idx) # takes 50sec
```

#### numpy_indexed [int -> np.array]

```
# thanks @Eelco Hoogendoorn for his library
values = npi.group_by(cubes).split(np.arange(len(cubes)))
result = dict(enumerate(values))
# takes 9.8sec
```

#### Pandas + dimensionality reduction [int -> np.array(dtype=int64)]

```
# thanks @Divakar for showing numexpr library:
import numexpr as ne
def dimensionality_reduction(cubes):
    #cubes = cubes - np.min(cubes, axis=0) #in case some coords are negative 
    cubes = cubes.astype(np.int64)
    s0, s1 = cubes[:,0].max()+1, cubes[:,1].max()+1
    d = {'s0':s0,'s1':s1,'c0':cubes[:,0],'c1':cubes[:,1],'c2':cubes[:,2]}
    c1D = ne.evaluate('c0+c1*s0+c2*s0*s1',d)
    return c1D
cubes = dimensionality_reduction(cubes)
result = pd.DataFrame(cubes).groupby([0]).indices
# takes 2.5 seconds
```

It's possible to download `cubes.npz` file [here](https://github.com/loijord/lidar_home/blob/master/cubes.npz) and use a command

```
cubes = np.load('cubes.npz')['array']
```

to check performance time.

Comment: Do you always have the same number of indices in each list in your result?

Comment: Yes, it is always the same: 983234 distinct cubes for all the solutions above mentioned.

Comment: It is unlikely that such a simple Pandas solution would be beaten by a simple approach, as a great deal of effort has been spent into optimizing it. A Cython-based approach could probably approach it, but I doubt it would outperform it.

Comment: @mathfux Do you have to have the final output as a dictionary or would it be okay to have the groups and their indices as two outputs?

Comment: @norok2 `numpy_indexed` only approaches it too. I guess it's right. I use `pandas` for my classification processes currently.

Comment: @Divakar Good point! I prefer to have an output as a dictionary where keys are tuples of 3 coordinates. But it's not neccessary. Let this be any dictionary that preserves second output as values. Btw, I keep a command `dict(enumerate(values))` costless because it takes only 0.15 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: @mathfux That was the point Mykola Zotko was asking about if every group/cube would have exactly the same number of indices, which is 4 in your small dataset. But, apparently in your `np.load('cubes.npz')['array']` case, upon using `np.unique`, it reveals that the number is not a constant, but varies.

Comment: @mathfux Also, I am not sure what is `values` for you. In the expected dictionary output, I see the keys as the 3D coordinates and the indices as the values. Can you clarify on what you said earier about `it's not neccessary.`. Is there any other output format - dictionary  or non-dictionary format that could work for you? From the timings I see this conversion to dictionary being the bottleneck. So, clarification on this could influence the solutions in a big way.

Comment: I mean it's not necessary keys are tuples of 3 coordinates. It can be anything that is hashable.

Comment: @mathfux Appreciate the bounty! So, did either of the posted solutions solve the question for you?

Comment: I didn't have time to review all the answers in details yet but I'm going to post summaries of my post in a week. I appreciate a variety of new methods and packages used that I haven't met before. Even more than efficiency of code. It will help to solve similar problems in a future for me definitely. Many thanks to you.

Comment: My current solution uses `dimensionality-reduction` achieved by using this '`c0+c1*s0+c2*s0*s1`' - like looking thing and `groupby` method of Pandas. So it takes around 5sec of consumption instead of 9sec in a case of my post. I need to check all the answers if it can speed up even more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Constant number of indices per group

#### Approach #1

We can perform `dimensionality-reduction` to reduce `cubes` to a 1D array. This is based on a mapping of the given cubes data onto a n-dim grid to compute the linear-index equivalents, discussed in detail [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/). Then, based on the uniqueness of those linear indices, we can segregate unique groups and their corresponding indices. Hence, following those strategies, we would have one solution, like so -

```
N = 4 # number of indices per group
c1D = np.ravel_multi_index(cubes.T, cubes.max(0)+1)
sidx = c1D.argsort()
indices = sidx.reshape(-1,N)
unq_groups = cubes[indices[:,0]]

# If you need in a zipped dictionary format
out = dict(zip(map(tuple,unq_groups), indices))
```

**Alternative #1 :** If the integer values in `cubes` are too large, we might want to do the `dimensionality-reduction` such that the dimensions with shorter extent are choosen as the primary axes. Hence, for those cases, we can modify the reduction step to get `c1D`, like so -

```
s1,s2 = cubes[:,:2].max(0)+1
s = np.r_[s2,1,s1*s2]
c1D = cubes.dot(s)
```

#### Approach #2

Next up, we can use [`Cython-powered kd-tree` for quick nearest-neighbor lookup](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html) to get nearest neighbouring indices and hence solve our case like so -

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

idx = cKDTree(cubes).query(cubes, k=N)[1] # N = 4 as discussed earlier
I = idx[:,0].argsort().reshape(-1,N)[:,0]
unq_groups,indices = cubes[I],idx[I]
```

---

### Generic case : Variable number of indices per group

We will extend the argsort based method with some splitting to get our desired output, like so -

```
c1D = np.ravel_multi_index(cubes.T, cubes.max(0)+1)

sidx = c1D.argsort()
c1Ds = c1D[sidx]
split_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,c1Ds[:-1]!=c1Ds[1:],True])
grps = cubes[sidx[split_idx[:-1]]]

indices = [sidx[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(split_idx[:-1],split_idx[1:])]
# If needed as dict o/p
out = dict(zip(map(tuple,grps), indices))
```

**Using 1D versions of groups of `cubes` as keys**

We will extend earlier listed method with the groups of `cubes` as keys to simplify the process of dictionary creating and also make it efficient with it, like so -

```
def numpy1(cubes):
    c1D = np.ravel_multi_index(cubes.T, cubes.max(0)+1)        
    sidx = c1D.argsort()
    c1Ds = c1D[sidx]
    mask = np.r_[True,c1Ds[:-1]!=c1Ds[1:],True]
    split_idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    indices = [sidx[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(split_idx[:-1],split_idx[1:])]
    out = dict(zip(c1Ds[mask[:-1]],indices))
    return out
```

Next up, we will make use of `numba` package to iterate and get to the final hashable dictionary output. Going with it, there would be two solutions - One that gets the keys and values separately using `numba` and the main calling will zip and convert to dict, while the other one will create a `numba-supported` dict type and hence no extra work required by the main calling function.

Thus, we would have first `numba` solution :

```
from numba import  njit

@njit
def _numba1(sidx, c1D):
    out = []
    n = len(sidx)
    start = 0
    grpID = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        if c1D[sidx[i]]!=c1D[sidx[i-1]]:
            out.append(sidx[start:i])
            grpID.append(c1D[sidx[start]])
            start = i
    out.append(sidx[start:])
    grpID.append(c1D[sidx[start]])
    return grpID,out

def numba1(cubes):
    c1D = np.ravel_multi_index(cubes.T, cubes.max(0)+1)
    sidx = c1D.argsort()
    out = dict(zip(*_numba1(sidx, c1D)))
    return out
```

And second `numba` solution as :

```
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict

int_array = types.int64[:]

@njit
def _numba2(sidx, c1D):
    n = len(sidx)
    start = 0
    outt = Dict.empty(
        key_type=types.int64,
        value_type=int_array,
    )
    for i in range(1,n):
        if c1D[sidx[i]]!=c1D[sidx[i-1]]:
            outt[c1D[sidx[start]]] = sidx[start:i]
            start = i
    outt[c1D[sidx[start]]] = sidx[start:]
    return outt

def numba2(cubes):
    c1D = np.ravel_multi_index(cubes.T, cubes.max(0)+1)    
    sidx = c1D.argsort()
    out = _numba2(sidx, c1D)
    return out
```

Timings with `cubes.npz` data -

```
In [4]: cubes = np.load('cubes.npz')['array']

In [5]: %timeit numpy1(cubes)
   ...: %timeit numba1(cubes)
   ...: %timeit numba2(cubes)
2.38 s ± 14.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.13 s ± 25.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.8 s ± 5.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Alternative #1 :** We can achieve further speedup with `numexpr` for large arrays to compute `c1D`, like so -

```
import numexpr as ne

s0,s1 = cubes[:,0].max()+1,cubes[:,1].max()+1
d = {'s0':s0,'s1':s1,'c0':cubes[:,0],'c1':cubes[:,1],'c2':cubes[:,2]}
c1D = ne.evaluate('c0+c1*s0+c2*s0*s1',d)
```

This would be applicable at all places that require `c1D`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response! I didn't expect usage of cKDTree is possible here. However, there are still some problems with your #Approach1. The length of output is 915791 only. I guess this is some kind of conflict between `dtypes` `int32`and `int64`

Comment: @mathfux I am assuming `number of indices per group would be a constant number` that I gathered off the comments. Would that be a safe assumption? Also, are you testing `cubes.npz` for the output of `915791`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I didn't test number of indices per group because order of group names may be different. I test the length of dictionary of output from `cubes.npz` only and it was `983234` for the other approaches I suggested.

Comment: @mathfux Check out `Approach #3 ` for that generic case of variable number of indices.

Comment: Thanks you very much for a new approach.

Comment: I am impressed by the numbers you get with Numba. However, in my version of numba (0.40.1) I have no submodule that goes by `numba.typed`, so I could not test one variant.

Comment: @norok2 Yeah, that's a recent addition, so one needs to update `numba`.

Comment: @Divakar I've tested `numexpr` based solution, that's brilliant! Only two issues are worth attention: 1) product of maximum coordinates exceeds boundaries of `int32` so we need to change type to `int64`; 2) `s0, s1` can't be just `max+1` if coordinates are negative. In this case I would change `cubes` to `cubes - np.min(cubes, axis=0)`

Comment: @mathfux Yup that offsetting is needed generally if the minimum is less than 0. Good catch on the precision!

Answer (score 5):

You might just iterate and add the index of each element to the corresponding list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

for idx, elem in enumerate(cubes):
    #res[tuple(elem)].append(idx)
    res[elem.tobytes()].append(idx)
```

Runtime can be further improved by using [tobytes()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) instead of converting the key to a tuple.

Comment: I'm trying to do review of performance time at the moment (for 20M points). It seems that my solution is more efficient in terms of time because iteration is avoided. I agree, memory consumption is enormous.

Comment: another proposal `res[tuple(elem)].append(idx)` took 50 seconds vs its edition `res[elem[0], elem[1], elem[2]].append(idx)` which took 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Cython:

```
%%cython -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True, infer_types=True

import math
import cython as cy

cimport numpy as cnp


cpdef groupby_index_dict_cy(cnp.int32_t[:, :] arr):
    cdef cy.size_t size = len(arr)
    result = {}
    for i in range(size):
        key = arr[i, 0], arr[i, 1], arr[i, 2]
        if key in result:
            result[key].append(i)
        else:
            result[key] = [i]
    return result
```

but it will not make you faster than what Pandas does, although it is the fastest after that (and perhaps the `numpy_index` based solution), and does not come with the memory penalty of it.
A collection of what has been proposed so far is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eRWXMpstnKrdeOim1HmaIm2OCAhYWQnG).

In OP's machine that should get close to ~12 sec execution time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it later.