# How can a numpy array replaced by another numpy array with other dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a small numpy problem where I am trying to replace the values from A with values of B.
See MWE:

```
t = np.arange(65,70,2)
>>array([65, 67, 69])

b = np.random.randint(3,size=20)
>>array([2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2])
```

Now `b` should be masked by `t` so that 2 correspond to the third element of `t` and 0 to the first element of `t`.

Whats the most efficient way to do this with numpy?

Comment: Just index `t` with `b`, `t[b]`

Comment: ah I tried `b[t]`. But y thats the best way.

Comment: So you need to access indices of 0, 1, 2 as fast as possible, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1**

For a simple use you can just replace items of `b` like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    b[b==i] = t[i]
```

It's quite fair but not efficient, especially if you play with huge ranges of indexes.

**Way 2**

If you would like to optimize it, you need to use grouping like I have discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239886/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-map-group-names-of-numpy-array-to-indices). Borrowing from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336298/3044825) of Divakar, `numpy`- only solution requires some deeper understanding:

```
b = np.array([2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2])
sidx = np.argsort(b) #indices that would sort an array
bs = b[sidx] #sorted array
# locations of changings in sorted array, [ 0,  3,  7, 20] in this case:
split_idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,bs[:-1]!=bs[1:],True])
indices = [sidx[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(split_idx[:-1], split_idx[1:])]
```

Indices is list of arrays `[ 9, 17, 15]`, `[2, 4, 7, 8]`, `[16, 14, 13, 12, 0, 10, 18,  6,  5,  3,  1, 11, 19]` which is equivalent to `b==0`, `b==1`, `b==2`, so you can use them now like so:

```
for i in range(len(indices)):
    b[indices[i]] = t[i]
```

**Way 3**

This is the most efficient way I've found but `numpy` is not enough here:

```
import pandas as pd
indices = pd.DataFrame(b).groupby([0]).indices.values()
for i in range(len(indices)):
    b[indices[i]] = t[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension for this:

```
[t[b_elem] for b_elem in b]
```

Comment: Also, the right solution even though indexing will be faster?!