# Dividing 3D data into cubic subsets and counting the points inside the cube

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a archive of data. (xx,yy,EXTRA) and  I want to divide the data into grids of equal size. For example, lets suppose that the data is:

```
xx=np.array([0.1,  0.2,   3,   4.1,  3, 0.1])  
yy=np.array([0.35, 0.15, 1.5,  4.5, 3.5, 3])
EXTRA=np.array([0.01,0.003,2.002,4.004,0.5,0.2])
```

I want to make square grids of size 1x1, and after obtain the sum of "EXTRA" for every point on the grid.

This is what I tried

```
import math

for i in range(0,5):   
    for j in range(0,5):
        for x,y in zip(xx,yy):
           k=math.floor(x)
           kk=math.floor(y)
           if i<=k<i+1.0 and j<=kk<j+1.0:
               print("(x,y)=" ,x,",",y,",","(i,j)=",i,",",j ,"Unkow sum of EXTRA")
```

I obtain as output

```
(x,y)= 0.1 , 0.35 , (i,j)= 0 , 0 Unkow sum of extra
(x,y)= 0.2 , 0.15 , (i,j)= 0 , 0 Unkow sum of extra
(x,y)= 0.1 , 3.0 , (i,j)= 0 , 3 Unkow sum of extra
(x,y)= 3.0 , 1.5 , (i,j)= 3 , 1 Unkow sum of extra
(x,y)= 3.0 , 3.5 , (i,j)= 3 , 3 Unkow sum of extra
(x,y)= 4.1 , 4.5 , (i,j)= 4 , 4 Unkow sum of extra
```

So, the first two points have coordinates (0.1,0.35) and (0.2,0.15) and are    inside the cuadrant (0,0). Looking in "EXTRA" I know that in the cuadrant (0,0)  I should obtain that the sum of "EXTRA" should be Sum_extra= 0.01+0.003. However I can't figure out how to make that sum in terms of code.

**More information**

My real problem is that I have "particles" inside a big cubic box, and I want to subdivide the box in smaller boxes, and in each one of the smaller boxes I want to obtain the sum of their "mass", in my example "EXTRA=mass".

I suspect that the way I classify whether a particle belongs to a quadrant is slow, which would suppose a problem since I have a lot of data.Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `I suspect that ... is slow` - did you do any testing to validate this?

Comment: Not yet, I'm working with smaller samples before I do the full work. However I think that I find a simpler way to do what I want, I will post the solution as a comment if it works.

Comment: You can also take a look at [my research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239886/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-map-group-names-of-numpy-array-to-indices) of the fastest solution in 3D.

Comment: `pandas` appears to win here but you can achieve 2x - 3x speed-ups if you use dimensionality reduction.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the three arrays with zip and sort the result on the `xx` and `yy` values. Then group that by the `xx` and `yy` values. Get the sum of the `EXTRA` values for each group.

```
import operator, itertools
important = operator.itemgetter(0,1)
xtra = operator.itemgetter(-1)
data = sorted(zip(xx.astype(int),yy.astype(int),EXTRA),key=important)
gb = itertools.groupby(data,important)
for key,group in gb:
    values = list(map(xtra,group))
    print(key,values,sum(values))
    # or just
    #print(key,sum(map(xtra,group)))
```

---

Same concept using a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
xx, yy = xx.astype(int),yy.astype(int)

In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({'xx':xx,'yy':yy,'EXTRA':EXTRA})

In [26]: df.groupby(['xx','yy'])['EXTRA'].sum()
Out[26]: 
xx  yy
0   0     0.013
    3     0.200
3   1     2.002
    3     0.500
4   4     4.004
Name: EXTRA, dtype: float64
```