# Python: searching a sequence (1,1,2) in a numpy vector (contains random 0,1,2 numbers) with for loop:

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, random, sequence

The code I have tried

```
rand_array2 = np.random.randint(0,3, size=1000)
rand_array2
```

Searching for a way that allows me to count the `(1,1,2)` Sequences in `rand_array2` with a for a loop.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide how to ask questions

Comment: Does this answer your question (this is for mutliple sequences, but you can use just one)? [Find the row indexes of several values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could look like:

```
import numpy as np
rand_array2 = np.random.randint(0,3, size=1000) 
pattern = np.array((1,1,2))    
matches=0
for i in range(len(rand_array2)-len(pattern)+1):
    match = rand_array2[i:i+3]==pattern
    if match.all():
        matches+=1
matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Here we loop through the range of the random array and match any sequences. This should work with any size of sequence as long as it's less than the length of the random array.

```
seq = (1, 1, 2)
arr = (1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1)
count = 0
for i in range(len(arr) - len(seq) + 1):
    if seq == arr[i:i+len(seq)]:
        count += 1
```

Edit: was a bit late.