# Find the index location of an element in a Numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

If I have:

```
x = np.array(([1,4], [2,5], [2,6], [3,4], [3,6], [3,7], [4,3], [4,5], [5,2]))

for item in range(3):
    choice = random.choice(x)
```

How can I get the index number of the random choice taken from the array?

I tried:

```
indexNum = np.where(x == choice)
print(indexNum[0])
```

But it didn't work.

I want the output, for example, to be something like:

```
chosenIndices = [1 5 8]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the row indexes of several values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by converting the **numpy** array to **list of tuples** and then apply the **index** function.

This would work:

```
import random
import numpy as np
chosenIndices = []
x = np.array(([1,4], [2,5], [2,6], [3,4], [3,6], [3,7], [4,3], [4,5], [5,2]))
x = x.T
x = list(zip(x[0],x[1]))
item = 0
while len(chosenIndices)!=3:
    choice = random.choice(x)
    indexNum = x.index(choice)
    if indexNum in chosenIndices: # if index already exist, then it will rerun that particular iteration again.
        item-=1
    else:
        chosenIndices.append(indexNum)
print(chosenIndices) # Thus all different results.
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! just one more thing, is there a way to have each index only taken once?

Comment: @AdryanZiegler Yes, I edited the code for that.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thanks a lot!

i tweaked it a little bit and removed the "item" from the whole code, and made it: 
if indexNum not in chosenIndicies: append

Comment: @AdryanZiegler That's great. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is using `np.where` and `np.intersect1d`. Here random choice without repetition.

```
x = np.array(([1,4], [2,5], [2,6], [3,4], [3,6], [3,7], [4,3], [4,5], [5,2]))

res=[]
cont = 0

while cont<3:
    choice = random.choice(x)
    ind = np.intersect1d(np.where(choice[0]==x[:,0]),np.where(choice[1]==x[:,1]))[0]
    if ind not in res:
        res.append(ind)
        cont+=1

print (res)

# Output [8, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Thats just perfect! thanks you so much!

Just one more thing, is there a way to have each index only taken once? so i dont get same index more than once? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the code, have a look at it. Just ask for example if the index is not in the result.