# Getting the indices of several elements in a NumPy array (can be repeated) at once

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to get the indices of several elements in a NumPy array at once?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([1, 1, 3, 2, 4])
```

I would like to find the index of each element of `a` in `b`, namely: `[0, 1, 3, 4]`.

**Please Note:**

1. `b` **has duplicated values**, e.g. `1` here, methods for example in [Getting the indices of several elements in a NumPy array at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191029/getting-the-indices-of-several-elements-in-a-numpy-array-at-once/61810956?noredirect=1#comment109330821_61810956) would not work because it only find left-most or right-most index, not all indices. So using the method there would get `[0, 3, 4]` if left-most applied.
2. **I want to honour the order of the values in `a`**, i.e. the first digits in the result is for the first value in `a`, and second few digits are for second value in `a` and so on, e.g. `[0, 1]` is for `1` in `a`, `[3]` is for `2` in `a`, and `[4]` is for `4` in `a`, so order in answer is `[0, 1, 3, 4]`

Comment: @Divakar: The solutions in the duplicate does not consider the condition that the `b` array can have duplicate values. The answers there does not really work in this more complex case.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica You need to read more on the accepted answer there. `Searchsorted` solution with `sorter` works.

Comment: @Divakar: That solution will not consider any duplicates in `b` (note that `a` and `b` are swapped with the `A` and `B` in the linked question, i.e. `a=B` and `b=A` due to how the question is phrased). Using `searchsorted` with `sorter` for the example in the question will give `[0, 3, 4]` while OP wants `[0,1,3,4]`.

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica Got it. reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to my friend @rongkaizhang, I posted his beautiful answer here.

```
np.where(b == np.expand_dims(a, axis=1))[1]
```