# Python numpy: Selecting array entries based on input array

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

Assume I have an array:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Now I want to find the indices of elements in this array corresponding to the values given by another array input:

```
input = np.array([2,4,5])
```

The expected result should be:

```
result = [1,3,4]
```

A boolean mask, which is true for element indices 1,3,4 would also be fine.

I do not want to use looping to solve this. I assume that a possible solution has to do with the numpy where() function, but using this one, I am only able to compare the entries of array a with one element of array input at a time. Because the length of input might differ, I cannot really use this approach. Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your array 1-D?

Comment: Dupe of [Getting the indices of several elements in a NumPy array at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191029/getting-the-indices-of-several-elements-in-a-numpy-array-at-once)

Comment: `np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(a, input))`

Answer (score 0):

```
np.where(np.in1d(a, inp))[0]
```

or:

```
np.isin(a, inp).nonzero()[0]
```

or as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191029/getting-the-indices-of-several-elements-in-a-numpy-array-at-once):

```
sorter = np.argsort(a)
sorter[np.searchsorted(a, inp, sorter=sorter)]
```

output:

```
[1 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where(np.in1d(a, inp))[0]` np.where(np.in1d(a, inp))[0]

Comment: The answer from the other thread worked perfectly. Thank you very much, you helped a lot.

Comment: please up the answer.thank u happy learning