# How to return indices of valid year in full range of years?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy array:

```
valid_year = np.array([1999, 2005, 2007, 2010])
full_year = np.array([1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010])
```

How do I find the indices of year that appear in valid year in the full range of year array? Without using any loop or search function.

The result should be like `np.array([0,6,8,11])`

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191029/getting-the-indices-of-several-elements-in-a-numpy-array-at-once

Comment: No loop and no search? It sounds like you tied your hands badly...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this input:

```
year = np.array([1999, 2005, 2007, 2010])
full_year = np.array([1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010])
```

You can use broadcasting comparison and [`nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nonzero.html):

```
(year == full_year[:,None]).any(1).nonzero()[0]
```

output:

```
array([ 0,  6,  8, 11])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that the `full range of year` consists of consecutive years. With that in mind, we can just subtract the valid years by the minimum year in the range and get the desired result.

```py
>>> valid = np.array([1999, 2005, 2007])
>>> year_range = np.array([1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007])
```

Subtracting by the minimum year gives the result. You may also need [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to make sure the indices do not exceed the length of the year range.

```py
>>> valid - np.min(year_range)
array([ 0,  6,  8])
```

There you go, no loops or search functions. But to be honest, by subtracting the array and by using `np.where`, Numpy does perform loops behind the scenes. There is no actual way to avoid loops in this situation.

Comment: Very smart! +1 Regarding the use of loops, of course loops are everywhere, I guess only explicit loops are unwanted ;). NB. this wouldn't work however if a year in `valid` is not present in `year_range`

Answer (score 0):

The [`np.isin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html?highlight=isin#numpy.isin) function could be used:

```
import numpy as np

valid_year = np.array([1999, 2005, 2007, 2010])
full_range_of_year = np.array(
    [1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
)

boolean_mask = np.isin(full_range_of_year, valid_year)

print(boolean_mask)
# [ True False False False False False  True False  True False False  True]

print(np.nonzero(boolean_mask))
# (array([ 0,  6,  8, 11]),)
```

Comment: I don't know if `isin` counts as a *search function*